# Dell "Remote Access Configuration Utility" keeps prompting

Tags: remote-access, dell

One of our servers can never reboot without pausing at the BIOS prompt asking to "F1 to continue, F2 to enter setup utility".

I have gone into Setup and there is nothing there to stop it prompting for this; I have gone into the Remote Access Configuration Utility (CTRL+E) and have setup some values hoping that because it was setup it would not keep asking, but nope, nothing obvious like "Disable Remote Access Configuration".

This is the screen we see:
[image: Bios Screen]

Does anyone know what we can do to let our machine boot cleanly??

Comment: AFAIK, an unconfigured DRAC won't stop the server from booting. There's another reason it's stopping. Are there any other messages when the server POSTs?

Comment: Nope, all you see above is all we see

Comment: Hmmm... I've never heard of or seen an unconfigured DRAC cause POST to stop. A phone call to Dell is probably in order.

Comment: We're having the same issue at our shop. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This plaguing my PE2900 tower as well would like to see a solution.

Comment: I don't think that last line is DRAC but system setup. Press F2 and check if anything isn't configured (like boot device, drives etc).

Answer (score 3):

in my case, it was because the poweredge 840 server was using the onboard sata

i had enabled all 4 channels for auto detect but only 2 channels/sata ports were populated

once i disabled the unconnected ports; the f1/f2 error disappeared.

thanks to those that posted above for the thip

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem with Dell PowerEdge 2900 and BIOS version 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

There are some simple things that can cause this problem, I would make sure to remove any external devices before flashing the ROM. I have seen the issue caused by keyboards and mice.

In the BIOS, make sure your boot order is set correctly (perc@top), and disable any IDE or SATA channels that are not connected.

---

1)  Get a USB drive

2) Download the 1.5 version of the BMC: http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=08W&l=en&s=bsdv&releaseid=R270159&SystemID=pwe_t110&servicetag=&os=LHS64&osl=en&deviceid=5814&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=5&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=29&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=398147

file should be PET110BmcA03.exe, 7.2MB, extract

3) Follow these directions to create a bootable USB

4) Instructions for flashing:

Copy the firmware image file, firmimg.d6, the DOS executable,bmcfwud.exe, and config file, bmcfwu.cfg, to a bootable USB key/floppy in the same directory.  >>> Do this in step #3 above

2. boot off this media and execute "bmcfwud.exe" from the directory where the firmware image file exists. "-i" option can be used to specify the exact image path if not in the same directory.
3. Reboot the system to the same media as prompted.
4. Execute "bmcfwud.exe" again to complete the firmware update.
5. Reboot the system

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19351445.aspx